# What are the ways to send normal http requests from the front end?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, httprequest

1) It is not clear for me how and what are the different approaches for  sending `http requests` from the front end to the server?

2) The only thing that is obvious to me is when we are submitting a `form`  to a route handler in the back end or when we click a `button` and by default it is redirecting to another web page that it is all done by a normal http requests.

3) I was wondering can we send `http requests` like that in the back end but from the front end?

```js
const https = require("https");

const url =
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Florence";

https.get(url, res => {
  res.setEncoding("utf8");
  let body = "";
  res.on("data", data => {
    body += data;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(
      `City: ${body.results[0].formatted_address} `
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: If you mean in a browser, you can use XMLHttpRequest (commonly known as Ajax), or most certainly the higher-level versions provided by many JavaScript frameworks (jQery, Angular, etc.). If you mean on the command line, there’s ciel, wget and many others. If you mean from some other language, it will depend on said language (and possibly frameworks, OS...)

Answer (score 3):

1. > how and what are the different approaches for sending http requests

In front end (client side), you can make various requests to server.
For example:

- With native JS [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Just change default example from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to your case:

  ```
  function reqListener () {
   console.log(this.responseText);
  }

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  oReq.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Florence");
  oReq.send();
  ```
- With ES6 [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) module:

  - Using Promises:

    ```
    fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Florence').then(res => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e))`
    ```
  - Using async/await, we'll use [IIFE](https://api.jquery.com/get/):

    ```
    (() => {
      const result = await fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Florence');
      console.log(result);
    })();
    ```
- Another options:

  - [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/get/) requests:
    Just like this: `$.get(url, function(response) { //...Handle response });`

> About second question

You are always making `GET/POST` etc request to server. So, when you're calling google's api or visit Stackowerflow page, you exactly making request to server and it provide you with the answer. 
You can read more about requests [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

> 3) I was wondering can we send http requests like that in the back end
>   but from the front end?

It's better to use JS (front) solutions to use in browser, because they are intended for this case.